# Browser-side font scaling on mobile devices

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML and CSS file like

```css
* {
  font-size: 100%;
}

div {
  margin: 1em;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=320px, initial-scale=1.0"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      Let me zoom
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Using different desktop browsers and hitting `Strg` + `+` / `Strg` + `-` is zooming the font as expected. Changing the browser based font size (in settings) is changing the displayed font size as well.

But trying to change the font scale in mobile browser settings (on Android, tested with Yandex, Chrome), is changing either nothing or only some parts like margins but no font size. The only mobile browser where this is working as expected is Firefox. Please be aware that I'm not talking about user zoom by pinching but about changing the font size in settings.

Do I miss any css or meta setting or is this simply not fully supported by some mobile browsers? My aim is to make the design as accessible as possible and to support a user's wish to scale font browser-wide.

JSFiddle to play around with: https://jsfiddle.net/bk0ufrj5/1/

Comment: You probably just want `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />` you can see the other viewport meta tags here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: That was my initial setting and is of course the most common standard usage of viewport meta. Unfortunately, it doesn't allow to scale fonts as described. Setting the width in pixel only tells the browser to calculate everything at least with a total width of 320px (in my case) and scaling the content down if there is less space.